# is using the loopback address equivalent to the local ip address?

Tags: tcp, ip, localhost, loopback, nic

Using the loopback address 127.0.0.1 will bypass the NIC. If the local machine has some other ip address assigned to it, will traffic from that machine to the same machine using said ip address hit the nic? if it does, what performance impact does that have, if any?

Comment: What operating system? Windows 3.11 with Trumpet Winsock?

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't touch the NIC. Performance impact will be negligible.

Unless you are running a really dumb os, of course.

Comment: What about Windows XP?  Thanks

Comment: @eve, Windows XP is not **that** dumb.